# How to make a form run a code whenever he shows

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I got a form that contains controls in it, let's call the form `Form1`. The controls are generated when `Form1` loads. Whenever I press on a control, it leads me to another form, `Form2`, and **hides** `Form1` with this simple code which is located on `Form1`

```
   Me.hide() 
   Form2.show()
```

Form2 contains some controls. One of them is a control that let the user delete a record. Whenever a user deletes a record, `Form2` closes and `Form1` appears, by using the code:

```
   'Deletes record here
    Me.close() 
    Form1.Show()
```

The problem is, the Item that I have deleted in `Form2` still appears on `Form1` untill I close `Form1` and run it again.

Problem is, i don't want to close `Form1` because when `Form1` closes, it does another thing.

The function that populates `Form1` called `Initialize()`. How do I make this function run whenever I do `Form1.show()`? I tried put this function in the **shown** event in `Form1`, but it didn't help.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `Form1` contains Pictureboxes that are generated from a DataBase. The click event on the item opens up `Form2` which shows more information about the Picturebox. `Form2` has the abillity to delete the Picturebox, and whenever I delete the picturebox, I want to go back to `Form1`. When I access `Form1` after deleting the picturebox, The picturebox still appears in the form until I **close** the form and then run it again. The function that generates the pictureboxes from the Database called `Initialize()` and I want to run it everytime `Form1.show()` occures

Answer (score 0):

If you need to refresh `Form1` with updated data from changes made on `Form2`, try requerying `Form1`'s datasource.  Really, though, I think you should have an outer process containing instances of `Form1` and `Form2` instead of using the global instances.

if you want to call `initialize`() again before `Form1.show`, you can, but consider taking the code out of that sub and into your own custom sub and then call it from `initialize`() and before `form1.show`.  Say you called your picture loading sub `loadPics`().  you'd call `loadpics`() inside `initialize`() and before `Form1.show`.

Comment: what `Initialize()` does it extracting the data from the Datasource and generate Pictureboxes according to the information. The datasource is being changed when I delete a Picturebox on Form2

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution!

In order to run a code to be executed whenever you do `Form1.show()` just place the code you want to execute in the **VisibleChanged** event.

Hope it will help others!